# Fetch name when number of distinct names less than 200 mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose structure is as follows

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ app_id ║ app_name ║ categoryId ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║  1200  ║    A     ║     B      ║
║  1200  ║    A     ║     C      ║
║  1200  ║    A     ║     D      ║
║  1201  ║    E     ║     F      ║
║  1201  ║    E     ║     G      ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

Now I have 1600 such data. What I am trying to get is, a query to fetch data till the number of distinct appids reaches 200. After 200 is reached it should no longer fetch the rest of the data. I tried count(distinct(app_id)) but that doesn't seem to work the way I think. I am really struck here and it is a major performance issue. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT app_id  
FROM myTable
GROUP BY app_id 
HAVING COUNT(distinct app_id) < 200;
```

Comment: `COUNT(distinct app_id)` is always 1 since the query performs a `GROUP BY app_id`. Hence this query simply fetches all `app_id` values contained in the table.

Comment: Thanks Rahul that worked like a charm. I modified the query slightly to meet my requirements and it worked perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SathiyaNarayanan I fail to see how this query could possibly work. `COUNT(distinct app_id)` in the `HAVING` clause is always `1`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is

> a query to fetch data till the number of distinct appids reaches 200

then you can use variables to implement this:

```
SELECT app_id, app_name, categoryId
FROM (
  SELECT app_id, app_name, categoryId,
         @appIDcnt := IF (@appID = app_id,
                          IF(@appID := app_id, @appIDcnt, @appIDcnt),
                          IF(@appID := app_id, @appIDcnt+1, @appIDcnt+1)) AS cnt
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @appID := 0, @appIDcnt := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY app_id ) AS t
WHERE t.cnt <= 200
```

In the above query `@appIDcnt` variable is used to count distinct `app_id` values. The query fetches table data until `@appIDcnt` value reaches 200.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/501fb/6)

Answer (score -1):

use limit it will return the first 200 results only.

`SELECT DISTINCT ap_id FROM appTable LIMIT 200`

and then if you need to get the next 200 then use offset 200 which will start with row 201

```
SELECT DISTINCT ap_id FROM ap_Table LIMIT 200 OFFSET 200
```